# How can I link excel cell to updated value from web?

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, auto-updates

Is there a MS-excel function that allow to link data from the web?

I am tryning to create a model based on MS-excel spreadsheet with financial data.

How can I update the cells with the today value of a single debenture/equity found/stock? I think I have to use hyperlink but I do not understad how to find those data from a webpage.

All data I need are free available online

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I was asking if there is an excel function that link data from the web to a cell. I re-write the question in a better way. I am not able to write script or using VBA functions

Comment: Then you should employ someone to do the work or learn yourself.

Comment: @DavidPostill as suggested I studied (also with the help of other user from the web). Now you can see the solutions that works for me, and I hope also for other users

Comment: Well done. Nice answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution with office 2007 that I would like to share:

1. select "**data**" section an then click "**from web**"
   [image: step_1]
2. it opens a new **web-query** where you have to insert the web address of the page with the data you need
   [image: step_2]
3. if the data you need are included in a table you can import only that table, because tables are highlighted by a green arrow (otherwise you can import all the page)
   [image: step_3]
4. before choosing the cell where import tha data you can use option tab as you need
   [image: step_4_option_tab]

The screenshot are from my regional version of office